# What are the regional legislative parliaments in the EU that can veto treaties such as CETA, TTIP, or (later) the Brexit agreement?

Tags: european-union, trade, ttip, ceta

On 5 July 2016, the European Commission [announced](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_IP-16-2371_en.htm) that the ratification of the CETA agreement between Canada and the EU *will* involve ratification by national parliaments. The German newspaper TAZ [notes](http://taz.de/EU-Handelsabkommen-mit-Kanada/!5319462/) that:

> Deshalb soll das Abkommen nun so schnell wie möglich ratifiziert werden – durch das Europaparlament und 42 nationale und regionale Parlamente, Großbritannien eingeschlossen.

which means

> Therefore, the Agreement shall now be ratified as fast as possible — by the European Parliament and [by] 42 national and regional parliaments, including the United Kingdom.

I would expect that it should be ratified by the European Parliament and 28 national parliaments.  What is the role of regional parliaments in CETA ratification?  Which ones are those regional parliaments?  Can they block it?

There appear to be 74 regional parliaments in the EU (pre-Brexit), such as at [CALRE](http://www.calrenet.eu/) or [REGLEG](http://www.regleg.eu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&Itemid=9).  I suppose the ones who can veto treaties are a subset of those.  One of them is — apparently — Wallonia.  Which ones are the others?

Note [this seems to be 38 post-Brexit](https://www.rte.ie/news/brexit/2017/0516/875513-trade-deals-ecj/), (42 - Westminster - Holyrood - Cardiff Bay - Stormont = 38).

Comment: Some info may be at the [Conference of European Regional Legislative Assemblies](http://www.calrenet.eu/), but this unites *74* regional legislative parliaments whereas only 14 of those can veto CETA, TTIP, or Brexit.  Also at [REGLEG](http://www.regleg.eu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&Itemid=9).

Comment: The Guardian news paper had slightly a different count of 28 national and ten regional governments in an article from October 2016. https://www.theguardian.com/business/2016/oct/14/eu-canada-free-trade-deal-ceta-in-jeopardy-belgium-wallonia-parliament-vote

Comment: @origimbo That would be the post-Brexit figure: 28+10=38.

Comment: But post Brexit there will only be 27 national governments...

Comment: @origimbo True.  Perhaps the journalist got confused, learned there were 10 regional parliaments that can block Brexit, and assumed it would be the same for CETA.  UK regional parliaments cannot block Brexit, but I suppose they could have blocked CETA if they had chosen to do so?

Comment: @origimbo / gerrit The numbers in news media articles are to be taken carefully: it seems that the number 42 originates from an editing error, as I count 41 parliaments pre-Brexit (see answer below) plus the EU-parliament gives 42. So maybe there was before a phrase like "42 national and regional  parliaments including the EU-parliament" which should have been edited into "the EU-p. and 41 national a. regional p.", but the 42 remained in the text instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratification involves, as you've cited correctly, *only national parliaments*. Indeed are there only 27/28 member states (post/pre-Brexit respectively), but the total number of parliaments that have to ratify depends on the constitutions of the member states. The [following 13 states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_parliaments_of_the_European_Union#List) have a bicameral system,

- Austria
- Belgium
- Czech Republic
- France
- Germany
- Ireland
- Italy
- The Netherlands
- Poland
- Romania
- Slovenia
- Spain
- United Kingdom

Therefore, there are 28+13=41 national parliaments pre-Brexit and 39 post-Brexit involved in ratifying such treaties. (Note that certain member states can invoke a referendum for the ratification process). However, not all of these parliaments are required for the ratification (as pointed out in [the comment below](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11608/what-are-the-regional-legislative-parliaments-in-the-eu-that-can-veto-treaties-s#comment68954_19077)).

The [following document](http://www.epgencms.europarl.europa.eu/cmsdata/upload/7ce7f104-1295-48f1-962e-51eba78d5ace/Mixed_Agreements_FINAL.pdf) has an overview of all the specifics of the ratification process, and it shows that second chambers of Belgium, Ireland, and Slovenia do not need to ratify the treaty, which would be 36/38 national parliaments in total. In the pre-Brexit case, the House of Lords can just delay the process of ratification (see comments [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11608/what-are-the-regional-legislative-parliaments-in-the-eu-that-can-veto-treaties-s#comment68954_19077) and [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11608/what-are-the-regional-legislative-parliaments-in-the-eu-that-can-veto-treaties-s#comment68974_19077) below as well as notes related to UK in the aforementioned document).

However, Belgium is the exception here on all levels: The Belgian constitution transfers certain legislative powers down to regional bodies and even assemblies, the situation here is quite intricate.

The [same document](http://www.epgencms.europarl.europa.eu/cmsdata/upload/7ce7f104-1295-48f1-962e-51eba78d5ace/Mixed_Agreements_FINAL.pdf) summarizes the Belgian institutions involved in the ratification:

> **Parliaments  of  the  federated  entities:**
>
> - Flemish,
> - Walloon,
> - Brussels-Capital,
> - German-speaking Community,
> - Walloon-Brussels Federation,
> - French-speaking Community in Brussels,
> - Joint Assembly of the Common Community Commission in Brussels

The Belgian constitution is dividing Belgium into three regions (Wallonia, Flanders and Brussels-Capital) and three communities (French, Flemish, and German-speaking), where the Flanders region and the Flemish community are unified into one parliament.

> Each of the five components of the federal system (Flemish Community, French Community, German-speaking Community, Walloon Region and Brussels-Capital Region) have their own, directly elected unicameral council or parliament. They vote decrees (or ordinances in Brussels), that have the same value and are on the same juridical level as the federal laws. [¹](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Belgium#Legislative)

The Walloon-Brussel Federation is essentially the representation of the French community; the parliament is formed by members of the Walloon parliament and  French-speaking members in the parliament of Brussels-Capital [²](https://www.pfwb.be/en/the_federation_wallonia_brussels).

The [French Community Commission in Brussels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Community_Commission) needs also to be asked, since

> Unlike the Flemish Community Commission, the French Community Commission has been granted legislative power in some areas (such as tourism and healthcare) by the French Community. [ibid.]

And finally the [Joint Assembly of the Common Community Commission in Brussels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Community_Commission) has also legislative powers and is responsible for community matters that do not fall into the competencies of either community in Brussels.

---

Which of these bodies can veto other agreements like TTIP or the Brexit agreement depends on the content of the treaties. I suppose the Brexit agreement is not touching upon bilingual issues in Brussels, so probably the last body mentioned in the list will not be deciding about the Brexit agreement. The same is probably true for some of the other bodies mentioned in the list. But this is just speculation as long as there is no actual treaty text.

---

It is probably useful to cite the rest of the Belgium section in the aforementioned document:

> **Overview:**
>
> - The Kamer/Chambre has to approve all mixed agreements. The Senate/Sénat no longer has ratification powers.
>     ­
> - The parliaments of the federated entities in Belgium must also approve mixed agreements if the content of the agreement touches upon their competences.
> - Referendums are not provided for according to Belgian law.
>
> **Specifics:**
>
> The  draft/proposal  to  approve  a  mixed  agreement  is  sent  to  the  House  of  representatives  from  which point it is dealt with by the  competent committee. Following discussions and a vote in this committee,
>   the  text  is  then  subjected  to  a  vote  in  a  plenary  session  determined  by a  simple  majority.  Where agreements  directly  affect  federated  competences,  approval  from  the  competent parliaments  of  the
>   federated entities is required. There are potentially 7 parliaments concerned. The required parliamentary approval in Belgium is concluded only when all competent parliaments of the federated entities and the Kamer/Chambre have given their consent. There is no scope for a referendum on mixed agreements.

Comment: There are issues with counting all bicameral systems as 2 houses as well. For example in the UK the Parliament Acts means that only the Commons needs to actually pass legislation, the Lords can only delay it. Based on the following article, the Guardian is getting to 38 with 28 parliaments, 5 Belgian regional/community parliaments, and 5 upper houses, including Germany, Italy and 5 unnamed. https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2016/dec/21/eu-lawyer-members-must-approve-sweeping-trade-deals-brexit

Comment: Also does the Belgian constitution transfer power to the regions, or are they assumed to hold it? The difference between federal and unitary states possibly forms at least part of the answer gerrit wanted.

Comment: @origimbo You're right about the UK. But in your article it reads: *"In practice, this means the deal may have to be ratified by at least 38 national and regional parliaments, including the EU’s 28 national parliaments, at least five regional and linguistic parliaments in Belgium and at least five upper houses, including those of Germany and Italy."* I think *"at least"* is the relevant part. For some cases the situation is not 100% clear as  it depends on the content of the treaty whether a second chamber has to ratify it, too. Apparently Slovenia and Ireland do not need to.

Comment: Interesting!  So for CETA it's rather 38 national parliaments + 4 regional parliaments whose competences are affected by CETA, all of them in Belgium?  I will take a more time to study your answer over the weekend and then accept and award the bounty.

Comment: On terminology: in a bicameral legislature, the two houses or chambers together form the parliament; so it's incorrect to refer to just one of the houses as a parliament. Hence instead of "41 national parliaments", you could write "41 national legislative chambers".

Comment: Having said that, it's unusual to count legislative chambers in this context, as the relationship between two chambers in one parliament varies by country, and it is the ratification by a parliament that counts, regardless of how that is achieved and how its constituent parts are involved.

Comment: And another thing :-) In the UK, under section 20 of the [Constitutional Reform and Governance Act 2010](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/25/part/2), a treaty can be ratified even if the Lords object, so long as the Commons doesn't object, without additional delay. However, section 23 lists some exceptions to this which presumably require legislation for ratification, and so overriding the Lords would delay progress by a year.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff The specifics about the UK were mentioned in a comment above, but you're right. About terminology and dubious counting, your right too. But the news articles started it ;)